# Burning a program using WILLAR on AT89C2051

Tags: microcontroller, 8051, atmel

When I burn a program on AT89C2051 using `WILLAR`, for example:

```
#include <reg51.h>
#define port P3
void delay(unsigned int); 
void main(void)
{
    for(;;)
    {
       port = 0x0;
       delay(1000);
       port = 0x0ff;
       delay(1000);
    }
}

void delay(unsigned int a)
{
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int j;
    for(i=0; i<a; i++)
    for(j=0; j<120; j++);
}
```

It shows a message: `The data out of range will be ignored`. But if I use port P1, instead of port P3, my program burns successfully.

Where is the problem?

Comment: sir actually there is no error in program but when i burn this program in micro controller then it shows notification **"the data out of range will be ignored"**. when i test output on *port 3* pin there is no output value. if i take **p1** insist of **p3** it run correctly let me know why this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Port 3 is multy purpose specially reserved form `timer/read/write/interrupt/`.
other port are general purpose.
port0 and port1 may have pull ups 
you don't want to globally define port 3 instead you can use P3 in your program with hexa value

`port=0xff` instead of `port=0xfff`